# Why would my app crash in Chrome if I refresh a few times?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a web app that does a lot of DOM manipulation and uses CSS3 effects.

I'm repeatedly refreshing the page, and on every 4th or 5th reload, Chrome displays the Aw, snap page indicating a tab crash. I think the page is consistently crashing around that many refreshes, so I don't think it's a probabilistic thing, but rather stems from something building up.

How can I examine Chrome crashes to find out some potential culprit causes? I've tried taking CPU profiles and heap snapshots, and it doesn't look like I'm accumulating much memory.

Comment: Ever since the lasted update 5th Feb we are now experiencing this on our app as well.

Comment: Hi guys! We have the same problem on each computer in our office in our Rich JS Application. Do you have some ideas, how to fix or avoid this?

Comment: Glad to see we're on the same boat. :)

Comment: This appears to be fixed in the latest release of Chrome 40.0.2214.115

Answer (score 6):

We to are experiencing the same thing in latest chrome version 40.0.2214.111 on multiple computers.

We logged a bug with Chromium here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=456365

Feel free to add comments / star to help get on their radar.

It seems tough to debug as there is no crash data and running debug tools themselves will cause crashes.

We have not been able to re-produce in Chrome Canary.

Answer (score 2):

We were having the same issue using last version of chrome (40.0.2214.111).

In our case the app is using SoundJS and if we disable webaudio api for this library, the app is working ok.

```
if (navigator && navigator.userAgent && navigator.userAgent.match("40.0.2214.111")) {
           createjs.Sound.registerPlugins([createjs.HTMLAudioPlugin]);
        } else {
           createjs.Sound.registerPlugins([createjs.WebAudioPlugin, createjs.HTMLAudioPlugin, createjs.FlashPlugin]);
}
```

don't know if your are using SoundJS but just in case I wanted to add this comment.